# Which camera bag for a single DSLR camera plus 2 lenses?

Tags: dslr, camera-bag, storage

I'm looking for a shoulder bag for 1 DSLR, 2 extra lenses and a small flash. I will probably be picking up a 70-200mm f/2.8 lens, so the bag needs to fit that attached to a camera. The bag needs to allow the camera to be easily stored and retrieved one handed.

Comment: Depends how you want to carry it - do you want to hike with your gear, or is this just to stop it rolling around in the car?

Comment: Great question, a common requirement I think - been on the lookout for something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm leaning towards the [Think Tank Retrospective 20](http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/retrospective-20-pinestone-shoulder-bag.aspx) which looks like it meets all my requirements.

Comment: So you answered your own subjective question? Nice. I'm still deciding between this bag or one of the Lens Changers.

Comment: Well, it is the bag I chose. I got it a few weeks ago, and love it. Very highly recommended!

Comment: How is the bag 1/2 down the road? Still good? I have the Lowepro slingshot mentioned above and its way too small for a full size DSLR + 70-200 L + 2 lenses.  Will absolutely not fit with a battery grip.  I am looking for something roomier and comfortable. Would you care to share your experiences?

Answer (score 7):

[Lowpro slingshot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BAX50G) is an awesome bag.  Has a built in weather cover for light rain, and enough extra storage for keys, wallet, neutral gray card, etc.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of this bag.  Used it on a 2-week trip through a bunch of national parks in the American Southwest.  It was a great way to carry gear around when trails weren't in the best shape and still get to it for capturing shots.

Comment: This bag is great for photography while hiking or site seeing, it makes it so easy to swing the bag in front and grab your camera, with out dropping everything out of the bag. I a huge fan.

Comment: This bag does not fit a dlsr with a 70-200mm f/2.8 lens attached and 2 other lenses and a flash in the bag.

Comment: @jakub, what bag fits a 70-200 f/2.8 lens attached?

Answer (score 5):

I've got a [Tamrac Velocity 8](http://www.tamrac.com/5768.htm) and love it.  It's got good space, is very comfortable, and can be pushed out of the way easily.

Plus the accessory system makes it easy to add things like water bottle holders, filter pouch, etc.

Also, I was looking at a [Tamrac Aero Speed Pack 85](http://www.tamrac.com/3385.htm) yesterday and was quite impressed by it.

Comment: Agreed completely; I have this bag (a hand-me-down from my wife), and it's extremely easy to carry.

Comment: How tall is that Velocity 8?  My x10 is great on height but is just so huge that is sometimes gets in the way.  (I can keep a Nikon D50 on a Sigma 120-400mm zoom with the lens hood in the x10.)

Comment: I use the aero speed pack as my laptop bag so I can carry a street camera with me, and it's pretty good. Moderately comfortable for me (not something I'd hike with, something I don't mind hauling around all day), can carry a body with a lens attached, 2nd lens and a flash plus a few toys. 

The tamrac velocity 8 is my street kit bag. I use it to carry a single body with a single lens (tamron 28-300), and it works fine for that.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard finding a perfect bag so here are my top picks...

- [Skytop Trading Leather Holster](http://skytoptrading.com/) - This is my favorite case.  I use it for general photos such as street, short hikes, and museums.  (And I think it looks great.)
- [Lowepro Faskpack 250](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Fastpack-250,2086,14.htm) - I use this for travel.  Holds several lenses and bodies and I have even used the laptop section stuffed with a camelbak water bladder before camera bags with bladders were popular.  You can even swing it off one shoulder and use it like a sling bag.
- [Tamrac Velocity x10](http://www.tamrac.com/5770.htm) - My gear lives most of its life in this bag... mainly for it's size.  It's a HUGE sling bag but it's not very comfortable.  After 6+ hours of carrying this packed with pretty much all of my gear I realized that this monster is best at just getting me from point `A` to `B`.  I do like the fact it is so big I can keep my cameras with lenses and hoods mounted and the lens caps off. This allows me to switch camera quick, but at the expense of bulk (and weight.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [pentax crossover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IKKMT0) one. Lightweith and I can put Camera with one lens mounted + 2 others lenses (or even 3 if lens are small - like fixed focal ones) as well as extra stuff like battery, memory card, ... in the upper part

Answer (score 0):

I use a Lowepro Minitracker backpack but there are so many alternatives.

This is a nice site with pictures of many bags incl equipment: http://www.cambags.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Tamrac Adventure Zoo](http://www.tamrac.com/5513.htm)m Case and attach [lens cases](http://www.tamrac.com/g_modularaccessory.htm).

I absolutely love the system because I can take out only what I need on a given trip.

Comment: I had a similar model and it was good.  I never got a lens case though.

In general, I like Tamrac camera bags.